# Grails' templates and their DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, grails

As far as Grails' templates go, do they have their own DOM? Is it different from the DOM of the main GSP(parent GSP) into which a template gets loaded or does the template's DOM become part of the parent GSP's DOM? I'm having a hard time differentiating between these two DOMs and their relationship. Do they both have their own separate DOM ready moments? And so their own separate DOM ready clauses as far as javascript goes? If anyone can please clarify on these points. Much obliged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GSP, Groovy server pages, are server based. The DOM you are concerned with is the client-side browser DOM. To answer your question, no. The entire HTML document (even if it's made up of several GSP templates) is still one DOM within the browser.

Having said this, however, it also depends on how you are loading the content of the page. I'm assuming you are loading all the content in a single HTTP request.

Comment: What if a GSP is loaded first and then depending on a menu the user picks from you load the appropriate template. That would be a different http request correct?

Comment: Assuming you are using some type of partial page update, or ajax request, yes. That would be a new request. It would merge into the existing DOM but would have it's own ready event.

Comment: Aha, ok I think your last comment was excellently helpful. It does have its own DOM ready event. Cool. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

The separate GSP templates are built into a single HTML document before being sent to the browser.

Grails uses a framework called SiteMesh http://www.sitemesh.org behind the scenes.

Edit:
I guess the answer depends on whether you are using the `<g:render template="myTemplate" />` tag from inside a gsp or doing an ajax call and using the render method from your controller like this: `render(template: "myTemplate")`

The ajax call will inject the html from the template into the browser's DOM.